# Creating Postgres Schema on Runtime in Spring Boot

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to create a database schema. But it seems like the code did nothing.

```java
  public void myfunc() {
    executeSqlFile(getSqlFilePath("init_schema.sql"));
  }
  protected void executeSqlFile(String sqlFileName) {
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(sqlFileName);
    ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator(resource);
    databasePopulator.execute(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource());
  }
```

`init_schema.sql`

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "account_controller_integration_test";
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "account_controller_using_hikari_integration_test";
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "account_controller_using_memcached_integration_test";
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "gojek_helper_controller_integration_test";
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "integration_failure_controller_integration_test";
```

`log`

```
[] ... INFO  o.s.j.datasource.init.ScriptUtils - Executing SQL script from class path resource [sql/init_schema.sql] 
[] ... INFO  o.s.j.datasource.init.ScriptUtils - Executed SQL script from class path resource [sql/init_schema.sql] in 8 ms.
```

After the code ran, I run the following commands on console.

```
select schema_name
from information_schema.schemata;
```

`output`

```
schema_name
-----------
pg_toast
pg_catalog
public
information_schema
```

Comment: Maybe a missing `commit`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mention by @a_horse_with_no_name at the comment, I'm missing commit at the SQL file.

`init_schema.sql`

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "account_controller_integration_test";
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "account_controller_using_hikari_integration_test";
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "account_controller_using_memcached_integration_test";
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "gojek_helper_controller_integration_test";
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "integration_failure_controller_integration_test";

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```